# Import Error: No module named 'allauth.account'

Tags: python, django, heroku, django-allauth

When I try and login to my Django app, I am given this error when logging in on localhost

```
ImportError: No module named 'allauth.account'
```

But when logging in on the live app (Heroku), there is no error. Any thoughts? It makes it frustrating when I have to push the site for every small change I make on the portion of the site that you have to login to.

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'allauth',
    # 'allauth.account', Does not work when running the app

    #My apps#
    'home',
    'projects',
    'accounts', 
    'storages',
)
```

Project Structure

```
myproject
---accounts
   ---__init___.py
   ---views.py
---myproject
   ---__init___.py
   ---settings.py
```

Comment: Do you have your __init__.py files in the correct locations?  This error is often associated with not having the files necessary  Can you post the relevant directory structures?

Comment: @MichaelPlatt Added them in, but there is nothing in the `__init__.py` files

Comment: @MichaelPlatt No, I never added it in, because I didn't see a need for it due to the auth working in Heroku. I also have no idea how to add it. The accounts folder is custom FYI.

Comment: Right that was my mistake.  Was thinking about something else when I wrote that sorry.  Have you checked out this link yet? http://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html  It looks like you need to include some other stuff in your settings.py if it isn't in there yet.

Comment: okay, so I did everything in the doc, and at `pip install django-allauth --upgrade` it gives me a `No such file or directory: file_path_here` even though I can find it manually. Any thoughts?

Comment: If you do a `pip freeze` it shows that django-allauth is currently installed right?  Also, is this on a Linux machine or a Windows machine and are you doing all this in a virtual environment or without one?

Comment: Yes, it does show `django-allauth` is installed. This is on a windows machine, and is without a virtual env

Comment: When I set up `django-allauth` I added `'allauth.account'` and `'allauth.socialaccount'` to `INSTALLED_APPS`. I see that you have `allauth.account'` commented out, but the error message makes me think that is what you need.

Comment: @MichaelPlatt I added this in and it won't even run the localhost, it still gives me the  `Import Error` Im looking through the `allauth` directory, there is no folder named `allauth.account` only `allauth.socialaccount`

Comment: Maybe you got a bad instance of the `allauth`.  Cliche as it is, it might not hurt to do an uninstall and reinstall of that package.